# What does divisibility imply?

Tags: c#, math, integer-division

If a number `n` is divisible by the number `m` what does that tell us about `m`?
I'm looking for the amount of numbers, within a range, divisible by `m`.
Can I instead of checking all `n` for `n % m == 0` perform fewer operations in respect to `m` somehow?

```
        static public List<BigInteger> FindDivisor(BigInteger m) {
            List<BigInteger> list = new List<BigInteger>();
            for (BigInteger n = 0; n < BigInteger.Pow(10, 64); n++) {
                if (n % m == 0) {
                    list.Add(n);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: The amount of numbers divisible by `m` in a range `[a, b[` is about `(b - a) / m`. This question would probably get better answers in math.stackexchange.com than here on stackoverflow, since it's a question about math.

Comment: @Yunnosch I was trying to come up with the exact number using `ceil` but this would require drinking a cup of coffee, thinking more carefully to avoid mistake, and writing a proof. I settled on a simple comment and "about".

Comment: @Yunnosch Because simply looping from my lower to upper limit, while running no code in the loop, takes more than 3 hours. :)

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't know what you mean. This isn't trying to not calculate it. It's about calculating fewer things. I don't know how I can smooth out the edge cases of an approximate statement.

Comment: @Yunnosch
for (i = 0; i < 10^64; i++) {
if(i%m == 0){
count++;
} 
}

Comment: @Yunnosch The programming language doesn't matter. I'm asking about the relationship between number qualities.

Comment: @Yunnosch happy?

Comment: Tagging a question with "math" and then asking a question about math as it relates to writing performant programs is truly off-topic. Thanks for bothering so thoroughly.

Comment: This is a very specific programming question, it's just programming language agnostic.

Comment: That is actually a fair point.

Comment: Actually, Yunnosch gave you very good hints to write code that can work when he said "Think about 7..10, 6..9 and 5..8 for divisability by 3". These ranges all have the same length, but not exactly the same number of multiples of 3. What's the difference? How to get the exact number by examining the extremities of the range? Also, when you do write code in a langue, be careful with the symbol `^`, which usually means "xor" and not "exponent".

Comment: You have my reopen vote. If you accept that as a peace offering you might consider making an acutal [mre] in C#, because, trust me, that will get you more helpfully minded readers.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have a feeling that if this question is reopened it's going to go from being about the technicalities of how you ask questions, to the technicalities about how you write C#. Where the question isn't about either.

Comment: @Stef Don't know what .. means.

Comment: @MathildaV `5..8` is just the same as `[5,8]`. Some programming languages use the `..` notation for ranges and so some humans use it too.

Comment: I meant it the human way (or would have code-formatted). I just decided to not use the even more confusing "5-8".

Comment: I don't know what the hint is. There's 1 divisible number for m in a range of size m?

Comment: The answer is `(int)(b/m) - (int)((a-1)/m)`, where `[a,b]` is the range we're counting multiples of `m` in (with 0 < a < b).  This comes from the fact that the number of positive integers <= `n` that are divisible by `m` is `floor(n/m)`

Comment: Some speedup tips (ignoring the direct calculation): 1) calculate BigInteger.Pow once, outside the loop; 2) as soon as you have the first divisible number, the next is `m` further on, so you don't need to test-divide any more

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That's cool. I also want to know what the numbers are. Which got lost when I had to write a C# function instead of just describing my problem, I suppose. The goal isn't to find the count, it's to arrive at the count in a better way than checking `n % m == 0` for all n.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Ah! So once I've found the first divisor I can safely loop with `m` steps?

Comment: @MathildaV correct, if 12 is the first in your range that is divisible by 3, then the next ones will be 15, 18, 21 and so on.

Comment: Please keep in mind that 10-to-the-power-64 is a pretty large number, so that result list may become too large (and take too long to fill)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Good tip. Thank you :)

Comment: This question (and @HansKeﬆing's tip) seems algorithmically closely related to the [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).